# How to solve the system error &H80040E14 (-2147217900) in excel ADOB connection

Tags: vb.net, excel, ado, sqlconnection, vba

I am trying to get the data from a SQL database through excel, I am using a ADOB connection. It was working fine and now i get a run time error, do not know what is the cause of it. I have not changed a code. My following code is:

```
    Public Sub SQL_Connection()

    Dim con As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim StrQuery As String
    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    With ActiveSheet()
    .Unprotect Password:=*****
    End With

    Sheets(2).Range("A2:H2").ClearContents
    ........
    If CheckBox4.Value = True Then  
    strCon = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=******\SQLEXPRESS;" & _
            "Initial Catalog=testdata;" & _
            "User ID=test;Password=*****;"
    End If
    ........

If CheckBox4.Value = True Then
Const DB_CONNECT_STRING = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=******\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=testdata;user id ='test';password=*****"
Set myConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set myCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

myConn.ConnectionTimeout = 15
myConn.Open DB_CONNECT_STRING1

Set myCommand.ActiveConnection = myConn
myCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Rewind SET Cause = '" & Sheets(2).Range("I2") & "' WHERE RewindID = '" & Sheets(2).Range("J2") & "'"
myCommand.Execute
myConn.Close
End If

With ActiveSheet
    .Protect Password:=66090
End With

End Sub
```

Please help.

Comment: If you comment out the `myCommand.Execute` line, does it still error? This would suggest that the error is in your `CommandText`

Comment: Do I2 and J2 hold valid values - in particular is there an apostrophe in either?

Comment: @CLR: I tired commenting out, but i still get the system error when i run.

Comment: The error itself - according to Microsoft - means: **The query uses non-ANSI outer join operators ("*=" or "=*")** - though we can see that there are no joins in the query you're sending. Microsoft state that the fix is to either stop using non-ANSI joins, or to wind back the version number of the database to 80 or before.

Comment: If you're getting the error without running the SQL command, then it would suggest there is a problem with the connection string `DB_CONNECT_STRING` - perhaps the database is no longer compatible with it.

Comment: @CLR: I tried rolling back into database level 80. But still i get the runtime error, I tried running a simple example using "Select query" and pass the value from db to excel. it worked, but for my above logic it did not. is it something to do with the update statement.